Defaulted 3-way comparison generates more code than expected
Consider the following piece of code:
struct B {
    friend bool operator< (const B&, const B&);
    friend bool operator==(const B&, const B&);
};

struct D : B {
    friend std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const D&, const D&) = default;
};

bool less(const D& a, const D& b) {
    return a < b;
}

Operators < and == are intentionally left undefined to avoid optimizations related to their inlining.
When I look at the assembly code (gcc) for the less() function, it appears to be fully equivalent to the following (this is true for both std::strong_ordering and std::weak_ordering return types of operator<=>):
bool less(const D& a, const D& b) {
    if (static_cast<const B&>(a) == static_cast<const B&>(b))
        return false;
    else
        return static_cast<const B&>(a) < static_cast<const B&>(b);
}

whereas I was expecting to see this:
bool less(const D& a, const D& b) {
    return static_cast<const B&>(a) < static_cast<const B&>(b);
}

Why do compilers generate an additional call to operator==(const B&, const B&) instead of just calling operator<(const B&, const B&)? Is it a missing optimization or there is a fundamental reason to check equality?

Better godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4jqofTxoW

a guess from cppreference: implementing operator @ (@ being <, ==, and so on) is done by doing x <=> y @ 0. Thus x <=> y is performed first and in its defaulted version, without additional information will always test for equality first, before doing something else. I think that without additional information it cannot optimized...

https://godbolt.org/z/d8KxdGbY9: the compare function there shows that the defaulted implementation of <=> is what you're seeing in your assembly.

This is how synthesis of tree way commemorator is defined by standard.
[class.spaceship]

11.11.3 Three-way comparison
The synthesized three-way comparison of type R ([cmp.categories]) of glvalues a and b of the same type is defined as follows:

(1.1)
If a <=> b is usable ([class.compare.default]), static_­cast<R>(a <=> b).

(1.2)
Otherwise, if overload resolution for a <=> b is performed and finds at least one viable candidate, the synthesized three-way comparison is not defined.

(1.3)
Otherwise, if R is not a comparison category type, or either the expression a == b or the expression a < b is not usable, the synthesized three-way comparison is not defined.

(1.4)
Otherwise, if R is strong_­ordering, then
a == b ? strong_ordering::equal :
a < b  ? strong_ordering::less :
         strong_ordering::greater




Basically since in your example compiler do not see implementation of bool operator< (const B&, const B&); and bool operator==(const B&, const B&); it must assume that they can have some side effects and must follow above definition literally.
Question is now can compiler optimize this if it could see through bool operator< (const B&, const B&); and bool operator==(const B&, const B&); and prove they do not have any side effects?
Apparently it can https://godbolt.org/z/qzzjsxeYT but in such case also less2 is also optimized in same way. Note that after that assembly of operator<(B const&, B const&) is same as assemblies of less and less2, so operator< for B and D are equivalent.

The <=> operator for D is explicitly defaulted, which means that it will perform a three-way comparison for all of its subobjects, including the base class subobject for base B.
B does not have a three-way comparison of its own, so one is synthesized from == and < ([class.spaceship] p1.4):

The synthesized three-way comparison of type R ([cmp.categories]) of glvalues a and b of the same type is defined as follows:

[...]
Otherwise, if R is strong_ordering, then
a == b ? strong_ordering::equal :
a < b  ? strong_ordering::less :
       strong_ordering::greater




This implementation intuitively not ideal for performance.
It shows that you should prefer providing a <=> operator directly for your types instead of a < operator, even if that can give you a synthesized three-way.

I'm thinking it's a consequence of the defaulted implementation of <=>.
If I had this function to your snippet:
std::strong_ordering compare(const D& a, const D& b){
    return a <=> b;
}

You'll see that the behavior of <=> is to check for equality first and do a comparison if it fails (a plausible implementation of the mandatory lexical ordering).
Then according to cppreference:

Other defaulted comparison operators
Any of the four relational operators can be explicitly defaulted. A defaulted relational operator must have the return type bool.

Such operator will be deleted if overload resolution over x <=> y (considering also operator<=> with reversed order of parameters) fails, or if this operator@ is not applicable to the result of that x <=> y. Otherwise, the defaulted operator@ calls x <=> y @ 0 if an operator<=> with the original order of parameters was selected by overload resolution, or 0 @ y <=> x otherwise:

(emphasized mine).
So, your less function calling a < b is, in fact, calling a <=> b < 0, without possibility to get smarter and optimize, without the function and structure bodies.
